# Fetching csv file with batch and use it in sql statement

Tags: postgresql, batch-file, psql

I have an sql file (import_noeud.sql) that copy a csv file into a table.

```
\copy public.import_noeud FROM 'T:\Affaires\102\171205_noeud.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
```

I then use a batch file with psql statement to launch my sql file.

```
psql -h localhost -U postgres -d dev -v ON_ERROR_STOP=1 -f import_noeud.sql> 01.log 2>&1
```

For now on, every time the user want to reimport new points he has to go modify the from clause of the sql file.

**My question** is, could my batch file:

- open the windows explorer
- ask the user to fetch the csv file
- store the result (for example 'T:\Affaires\102\171205_noeud.csv')
- launch the sql file using the result

Comment: Yes it can be done.

Comment: I know how to make the batch file to open the windows explorer to fetch the file but how can I use the result in the csv file?

Comment: I am not with you.. You want the result in the CSV file? I thought you were lookin at imoporting th CSV into a table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's incorporate `vbs` into a `.bat` or `.cmd` batch file. `vbs` is used to select the file.
Save both the `vbs` and `cmd` files in the same directory.

**import.vbs**

```
Set wShell=CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set oExec=wShell.Exec("mshta.exe ""about:<input type=file id=FILE><script>FILE.click();new ActiveXObject('Scripting.FileSystemObject').GetStandardStream(1).WriteLine(FILE.value);close();resizeTo(0,0);</script>""")
myFile = oExec.StdOut.ReadLine
wscript.echo myFile
```

**runme.cmd**

```
@echo off
for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('cscript //nologo import.vbs') do (set "VBSoutput=%%a")
echo \copy public.import_noeud FROM '%VBSoutput%' DELIMITER ';' CSV; > SOME_IMPORT.sql
```

Now you can run the batch file, which will open a <kbd>Choose File To Open</kbd> window. Once selected and you choose <kbd>open</kbd>, it will then select the file and automatically push it to `echo` the `\copy...` to a `.sql` file. So let's say you browse to, and select:

```
T:\Affaires\102\171205_noeud.csv
```

it will echo the following to the `sql` file in this case named `SOME_IMPORT.sql`

```
\copy public.import_noeud FROM 'T:\Affaires\102\171205_noeud.csv' DELIMITER ';' CSV;
```

You can add the launching of the SQL file if you like as well to the batch file.

If you decide to change the name of the vbs script, please ensure you also change it in the batch string `('cscript //nologo import.vbs')`

Hope it helps.

Comment: I didn't think about doing it that way but it works just fine, thank you Gerhard!!

Comment: Other question, how can I modify the vbs script so it return a folder path instead of a file? (T:\Affaires\102\  instead of T:\Affaires\102\171205_noeud.csv)